# Нужен пустой запрос для MySQL/MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, mysql

Нужен какой нить пустой запрос для базы, в качестве пинга, проверять не отвалилось ли соединение. Желательно не привязанный к существующим таблицам и базам. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самая простая конструкция для MySQL - это `SELECT 1`. Но, стандартная клиентская библиотека и так имеет служебную функцию пинга. Например: [для PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-ping.php). В библиотеках других языков тоже должна присутствовать, потому что она экспортируется из `libmysql.dll`.

Comment: а что такой запрос (SELECT 1) возвращает?

Comment: Одна строка, один столбец. Значение 1.

Comment: какой столбец/строка? а если там нет базы/таблицы?

Comment: В MySQL есть таблица-пустышка `dual` для вычислений. Дает возможность не обращаясь к конкретным данным делать вычисления чего-либо:

    SELECT 1 + 1 FROM DUAL

Тоже самое короче можно написать:

    SELECT 1 + 1

[Например](http://shot.photo.qip.ru/004ki2-302LW7e/)

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста